# MacLaurin Series for $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I would need some help with a MacLaurin Series. The function for which I should find a MacLaurin Series looks like
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and I also know the answer how the MacLaurin Series should look like
$$f(x)=1−x^2+x^4−x^6+x^8+O(x^9)$$
but I do not not the steps in between.

Until know I have the following
$$f'(x) = -\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$
$$f''(x) = \frac{4x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}$$
$$f''(x) = -\frac{8x^3}{(1+x^2)^4}$$

So the series should look something like this
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} -\frac{2x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} + \frac{4x^3}{(1+x^2)^3} -\frac{8x^4}{(1+x^2)^4} + ...$$

or I am completely wrong? I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Yeah, you are quite wrong. The formula you are trying to use is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$ which has nothing to do with that thing that looks like $\sum_k f^{(k)}(x)$ (and what are the double minuses?). Moreover, the derivatives after $f'$ are wrong because, for instance, $f''(0)$ must be $\ne0$, while yours is $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the easiest expansion

$$\color{green}{\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n(1+\epsilon(x))}$$

then

as when $x\to 0$, $\; -x^2 \to 0$, we can replace $x\;$ by $\; -x^2$ to get

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...(-1)^nx^{2n}(1+\epsilon(x)).$$

Comment: Thanks! Through substitution the whole thing get's really easy..but I have two more questions: what das $\epsilon(x)$ mean? 
And can i say, since i know that the convergence radius $\rho = 1$ in the case of the easiest expansion, that the convergence radius is still 1?

Answer (score 3):

Plug in $u=-x^2$ into the series for $\frac{1}{1-u} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty u^i$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
The particular series you provided
$$T_f(x)=1−x^2+x^4−x^6+x^8+O(x^9)$$
is a Taylor series centered at $x_0=0$. Thus you have to plug that value into the derivatives, as the taylor series is defined by
$$T_f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}f(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^i}{i!}$$

Also, the derivatives you computed are wrong.

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=\frac{6x^2-2}{(x^2+1)^3}$$

Evaluated at $x_0=0$ we get
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f|_{x=0}=-2$$

As you see this matches the second coefficient in your series. Looking at the formula for $T_f$ we see that the second term in the series should be
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x_0)\frac{(x-x_0)^i}{2!}\vert_{x_0=0}=-x^2$$

We proceed identically for higher order terms.

The same can be achieved by evaluating the geometric series
$$\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}t^i$$
at $t=-x^2$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ix^{2i}$$

Answer (score 1):

The faster way to do this problem is to do a straight long division. Dividing the numerator with the denominator will give you the infinite series that you want.